# How to convert string to datetime in DataObject with ObjectDataSource

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql, webforms, objectdatasource

I have one class for selecting, updating and deleting record in db (sql server 2008) and one class for represent table record, i think it's call 'Activ record' design pattern.
Now, I have GriwView with editing, selecting and deleting items. Data source for this grid is ObjectDataSource:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource" runat="server" 
        TypeName="DBOrdinacniDoby.Hours" 
        DataObjectTypeName="DBOrdinacniDoby.Hour"
        onobjectcreating="ObjectDataSource_ObjectCreating" 
        SelectMethod="GetAll"
        UpdateMethod="EditHour">
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

In grid is types like: int, nvarchar, date, time and bit.
Method's EditHour parameter is class of Hour.
Hour have construct without parameters, but when program sets property 'DateFrom' - DataTime type in C# and Date in SQL Server, I got Exception: System.InvalidOperationException, Can't convert form string to DateTime.

Please help, how can I fix it?
Thanks, Sebastian

EDIT: I try add event handler for GridView RowUpdating and manually convert do DateTime like this:

```
e.NewValues[1] = Convert.ToDateTime(e.NewValues[1].ToString());
```

But still not working... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to fix this, is to subscribe to the `Updating Event` of the `ObjectDataSource`.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.updating.aspx

Codesample from one of my apps (where Article is my Business Layer class):

```
protected void odsArticleDetail_Updating(object sender, ObjectDataSourceMethodEventArgs e)
{
    Article item = (Article)(e.InputParameters["item"]);
    TextBox txtDate = (TextBox)this.dvArticleDetail.FindControl("txtDate");
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDate.Text))
    {
        item.PublishDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate.Text, "dd.MM.yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"));
    }
    else
    {
        item.PublishDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

`e.InputParameters["item"]` **must match the parametername** of your Business Layer method:
In my case:

```
public void UpdateArticle(Article item)
{
 // save changes into db
}
```

Comment: ObjectDataSource Updating event handle don't start... :/ I make new aspx page, I added objectdatasource and grid, sets object data source (ods) set breakpoint in code behind but i can handle updatind event handle... why? :O

Comment: @Sebastian: Create a new sample web application and try to reproduce your problem

Comment: Ok, I made demo web page. It's packaged web page folder (VS2010 .NET 3.5), where is one page Default.aspx where is ObjectDatSource and GridView. In folder Sql are store procedures for OrdinacniDoby class. OrdinacniDoby and OrdinacniDoba are build Class in Bin directory, namespace DBOrdinacniDoby. [link](http://wanted.czweb.org/Sebastian.zip)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add UpdateParametes where you define Type of parameter.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
     UpdateMethod="UpdateUser" ...>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="CreationDate" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="LastLoginDate" Type="DateTime" />
        </UpdateParameters>
```

Worked for me.